# jQuery first: selector not working after function run once

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

When the key down function runs the first time it does what I expect and changes the first class to addBack. Every keypress after that has no effect. html displayed below is after 1 keypress.

html:

```
 <h1 id="id1">
    <span class="addBack">H</span>
    <span class="noBack">E</span>
    <span class="noBack">L</span>
    <span class="noBack">L</span>
    <span class="noBack">O</span>
 </h1>
```

jQuery:

```
    inputBox.keydown(function() {
    $("span.noBack:first").removeClass("noBack").addClass("addBack");
    });
```

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Thanasis https://jsfiddle.net/HYUTS/y0jd2zxr/5/

Comment: @HYUTS: This line is resetting the content of 'id1' after every keydown event: $('#id1').html(emptyArray);. If you remove that it works. https://jsfiddle.net/y0jd2zxr/7/

Comment: @Richard Appreciate ya.

Comment: @Richard anyway you can list it under answers so I can confirm it solved?

Comment: @HYUTS: Just updated the answer I already posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original answer**

Seems to work for me just fine:

```js
$('#inputBox').keydown(function() {
    $("span.noBack:first").removeClass("noBack").addClass("addBack");
    });
```

```css
.addBack { color: green; }
.noBack {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="id1">
    <span class="addBack">H</span>
    <span class="noBack">E</span>
    <span class="noBack">L</span>
    <span class="noBack">L</span>
    <span class="noBack">O</span>
 </h1> 
 
 <input id="inputBox" type="text" />
```

Is anything else changing besides adding the class? Like changing the input (events) or recreating dom elements so that events get lost?

**Edited answer - Something more did seem to happen which caused the problem.**

Original fiddle (from comment below question): https://jsfiddle.net/HYUTS/y0jd2zxr/5/.

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y0jd2zxr/7/.

This line was resetting the content of 'id1' after every keydown event: 
`$('#id1').html(emptyArray);`.

If you remove that it works.